# While loop issue on second column using IFS

Tags: bash, while-loop, ifs

This seems simple, list the directory from the first field then list the directory from the second field. The fields from the input file are comma separated, e.g.: `XXXX1111111111112222,cool.com`.

I run the command:

```
./list_directories some_file.csv
```

The `list_directories` script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$1
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read WORKING STORE
do
    echo $STORE
    ls $STORE
    echo $WORKING
    ls $WORKING
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Here's the output:

```
/pathtothe/som/coolplace/Imlookingfor/cool.com/place/123/XXXX1111111111112222 : No such file or directorye/Imlookingfor/cool.com/place/123/XXXX1111111111112222 /pathtothe/som/coolplace/Imlookingfor/cool.com/placing/123/XXXX1111111111112222 fileindir.txt otherfileindir.txt lastofthefilesindir.txt
```

I know that both directories exist. Not sure if I'm getting caught up on the loop or on the IFS.

Comment: I suspect your CSV file has CRLF instead of LF as its newlines. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: Rather than setting `IFS` globally, set it just for the `read` command. `IFS=, read WORKING STORE`. Then you don't have to worry about restoring it after the loop.